# Can you use an index as an independent variable in linear regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares

My y is an interest rate. The independent variable I would like to use is one index divided by another: both indexes have a base of year 2012 = 100. So my independent variable is the ratio of one index to another over many periods. Is there any issue if I use this ratio as my independent variable in a regression to predict y?

I am wondering if there are technical reasons for why this may be flat out wrong to do. My thinking is it shouldn’t matter whatsoever… in this case, every one unit increase in my ratio which is based on two very particular indexes corresponds to an increase in y equal to the coefficient. As long as I know how the interpret the coefficient then this is fine?

Here’s the ratio but with base year 2007. https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=qLC

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to say without additional context, but so long as the indices are *exchangeable* then there should be no problem.

Exchangeability manifests as invariance in the joint distribution of the parameters of the model.  If, for example, I could reassign the indices to show a negative relationship/positive relationship then the model would be non-exchangeable.

Comment: Thank you. One index is the Wilshire 5000 Index, and the other is a US GDP index. Both indices have base year 2012 = 100. The idea of exchangeability is new to me. Can you tell me if these indices are exchangeable?

Comment: But does my overall thinking make sense when it comes to using pretty much anything as independent and dependent variables? The interpretation is the only thing changing right? If you use a super specific index as an independent variable, and another super specific measure of something as your DV, then you just know that your coefficient represents your change in DV given one unit change in IV. Right? Units don’t really matter in this sense…?